# Two mail server installs (for two domains) on Windows VPS with one IP?

Tags: windows, email, smtp, email-server, vps

I'm starting with 1 IP address and the supplied mail server software license supports only 1 domain.

I'm now adding a second domain to the VPS on the same IP address.  There's a LARGE increase in cost to license the pre-installed mail software for 2 or more domains.  For that reason, I'd like to configure a different mail server product onto the VPS to support the second domain. (I'm definitely not married to the pre-installed mail software).

My top constraint is that I really **don't** want to disrupt the pre-existing mail software which right now is successfully supporting the first domain.

Apart from the technical challenge of side-by-side use of a second product, there's no reason to break or disrupt the original domain.  And it seems likely (to me) that  full replacement of the supplied mail software, migration of the users, mailboxes, passwords, forwarding instructions, etc., will probably disrupt or break the original domain's mail.

<strike>Thinking toward the example in which IIS can be configured to support more than one domain on a single IP,</strike>

I wonder if there's a technique "out there" that will allow two brands of mail software to be configured onto the VPS, with 1 IP address, where 2nd domain is supported by the new mail software without disrupting the original domain/mail software.  I understand this might be wishful thinking, but I'm asking in case someone [possessing broad/deep knowledge] is aware of a solution that I'm simply not aware of.

Thanks

Comment: Comparing email to IIS, the better analogy to your situation would be to try and have IIS and Apache both running on the same server. It's possible, but only one of them can be listening on port 80. Multiple websites on IIS is the same as having multiple email domains on a single email server, which is what you're trying to avoid (at least in regards to the existing mail server software).

Comment: What's up with the downvote?  I have been deferential about the superior knowledge and skill required on the part of the person answering this question, and I'm sure the question can be understood correctly from the use-case without nit-picking the analogy I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

While it would be possible to have two domains sending mail from two separate mail servers via a single IP address, it is fairly involved to have two mail servers both receiving mail from a single IP address. The thing is that a mail server, to receive mail, has to be continuously listening on port 25, and that cannot be shared. IIS can serve multiple sites because there is only one program, IIS, listening for connections; similarly a mail server can listen for multiple domains because, again, there is only one program listening for connections.

The only way I could see to do this is to move your existing mail server to a different listen port for incoming mail, then have all mail go to your new mail server; and have that mail server configured to forward everything for the existing domain on to the non-standard port where the existing mail server is listening. Whether that would be as disruptive as replacing the existing mail server, I cannot say. If adding the new domain to your existing server is cost prohibitive, setting it up to forward the new domain to a new mail server likely would be at least some fraction of the same cost.

Comment: The idea of moving the old mail server to a non-standard listening port (if possible), and configuring new mail server to forward mail for the existing domain to the non-standard port is an interesting one.  The new mail server has a much more liberal license/price scheme; it's the old mail server license price that hockey-sticks when configuring it with an additional domain.  Without having dug deeper (*yet*) I don't know if, where, or how the forwarding arrangement would break but it sounds interesting to look into.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't. They both need to listen on the same ports (25 for smtp).

You can have one webserver serve multiple domains, but you can't run multiple web servers.